# Bash Time Difference Calculation

Tags: linux, bash, shell, time

I have a log file and I need to make some calculations between two jobs to find time difference.

In my log file I am supposed to calculate time between the jobs `incoming request` and `candidate list sent for` which took 2 seconds in the log below as an example;

```
2019-08-23 00:05:27 42303: incoming request: 1dd5.073f.5d5f0397 (156074 bytes)
2019-08-23 00:05:27 42303: store file: /papillon1/vrf/rq/1dd5.073f.5d5f0397.rq, len: 156074
2019-08-23 00:05:27 42303: registering process 42605 left to finish it's work
2019-08-23 00:05:27 42605: making search request for: 1dd5.073f.5d5f0397
2019-08-23 00:05:27 42605: 1dd5.073f.5d5f0397 is request for search by fingers
2019-08-23 00:05:27 42605: portions: 156
2019-08-23 00:05:27 42605: request pattern version 8
2019-08-23 00:05:27 42605: fingers mask: 1111111111; quality mask: 3011031110
2019-08-23 00:05:27 42605: saving request file: /papillon1/vrf/rqm/1dd5.073f.5d5f0397.rqm~
2019-08-23 00:05:27 42605: renaming request file: /papillon1/vrf/rqm/1dd5.073f.5d5f0397.rqm~ -> /papillon1/vrf/rqm/1dd5.073f.5d5f0397.rqm
2019-08-23 00:05:27 42605: request file saved /papillon1/vrf/rqm/1dd5.073f.5d5f0397.rqm
2019-08-23 00:05:27 42605: request is in queue: 1dd5.073f.5d5f0397
2019-08-23 00:05:27 42605: request 1dd5.073f.5d5f0397 registering time: 663 msec
2019-08-23 00:05:28 42303: waiting for 42605 to be finished
2019-08-23 00:05:28 42303: 42605 finished; waiting time: 0 ms
2019-08-23 00:05:29 43188: candidate list for 1dd5.073f.5d5f0397; 2 records
2019-08-23 00:05:29 43188: candidate list file size: 381
2019-08-23 00:05:29 43188: candidate list sent for: 1dd5.073f.5d5f0397
```

so I created a script that reads all the maps in the log file and make calculations between 2 jobs for that map. In the log above `1dd5.073f.5d5f0397` is one map as an example.

Also here is my full script;

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `grep 'incoming request:' a8.svrf.ear | sed 's/^.*: //' | awk -F'[ ]' '{print $1}'`
do
    var0=$i

    TIME1=`grep 'incoming request:' a8.svrf.ear | awk -F'[ ]' '{print $2}'`

    TIME2=`grep 'candidate list sent for:' a8.svrf.ear | grep $var0 | awk -F'[ ]' '{print $2}'`

    SEC1=`date +%s -d ${TIME1}`

    SEC2=`date +%s -d ${TIME2}`

    DIFFSEC=`expr ${SEC2} - ${SEC1}`

    echo Map ${var0} >> /home/st/anil/test.txt

    echo Start ${TIME1} >> /home/st/anil/test.txt
    echo Finish ${TIME2} >> /home/st/anil/test.txt

    echo Took ${DIFFSEC} seconds >> /home/st/anil/test.txt

    echo Took `date +%H:%M:%S -ud @${DIFFSEC}` >> /home/st/anil/test.txt

    echo =========================================================================


done
```

In my code I basically tried to get all maps with a for loop and for each map I tried to get time for 2 jobs and find the time difference but my output is something unexpected ;

```
=========================================================================
date: extra operand ‘00:05:27’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
date: option requires an argument -- 'd'
Try 'date --help' for more information.
date: invalid date ‘@-’
=========================================================================
```

I would be glad if you guys show my mistake. Thank you

Comment: Copy and paste your script to https://shellcheck.net

Comment: @oguzismail actually I used xclock and and when my script reads it line by line ++ grep 'incoming request:' a8.svrf.ear
++ sed 's/^.*: //'
++ awk '-F[ ]' '{print $1}'
+ for i in '`grep '\''incoming request:'\'' a8.svrf.ear | sed '\''s/^.*: //'\'' | awk -F'\''[ ]'\'' '\''{print $1}'\''`'
+ var0=1dd5.0721.5d5f02b1
++ grep 'incoming request:' a8.svrf.ear
++ awk '-F[ ]' '{print $2}'
+ TIME1='00:01:37
00:05:27
00:09:49
00:11:18
00:12:02
00:12:28
00:12:52
00:13:24 it keeps reading time from it.

Comment: Some of those "maps" are breaking your script. The input is probably not as consistent as you have assumed. Try `set -X` to see what arguments are being passed to `date` when the error occurs.

Comment: `-d ${TIME1}` should be `-d "${TIME1}"`

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use gawk instead:

```
gawk '
/incoming request:/ {
    d[$6]=mktime(gensub(/[-:]/," ","g",$1" "$2))
    next
}
/candidate list sent for:/&&($8 in d){
    print $8,mktime(gensub(/[-:]/," ","g",$1" "$2))-d[$8]
}' OFS="\t" a8.svrf.ear
```

<sub>this answer is based on the information provided in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198441/room-for-oguz-ismail-and-anil-asik) by OP.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have the wrong `date` version installed.

You can run `date --version` and you should get a similar output to this.

`date (GNU coreutils) 8.28 
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Written by David MacKenzie`

The `date +%s -d` options only works on the gnu version of date. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html

If you don't have this version of `date`, then you can just install it and your code will run fine.

For Mac OS X, use `brew install coreutils` and use gdate instead of date as that is the GNU version.

This is the result i get when i run it.

`Map 1dd5.073f.5d5f0397
Start 00:05:27
Finish 00:05:29
Took 2 seconds
Took 00:00:02`

Comment: I have "date (GNU coreutils) 8.22" on "CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)"